# boost::spirit::qi why doesn't recursive parser work as expected?

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'd like the grammar below to parse input such as

```
a_end
a_b_end
a_b_c_end
```

but it only parses `a_end` and fails on anything with more than one `_`. Here is the grammar:

```
template < typename Iterator >
struct recursive_parser : qi::grammar< Iterator >
{
    qi::rule< Iterator > start;
    qi::rule< Iterator > end;
    recursive_parser() : recursive_parser::base_type( start )
    {
        using namespace qi;
        end = string("_end") | start;
        start = +(char_ - '_') >> end;
    }
};
```

Are rules not designed to be used recursively or am I missing something more obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your grammar, and the input string `a_b_end` we have the following parsing occur:

```
In Start: consume "a". Iterate into end.
In End:   The next part of the string is not "_end", so the first alternative fails.
          Try the second alternative, which is to iterate into start.
In Start: The next character is a "_", so start fails.
```

So your grammar should be:

```
end = string("end") | start;
start = +(char_ - '_') >> '_' >> end;
```